# Can't make DuckDuckGo default search engine in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search-engines

I added it on the list of engines, but I don't have option "Make Default" in  menu for it. Another engines have it, but not DuckDuckGo. (I changed http to 
 https - misspelled on lower screenshot)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you followed [this procedure](https://www.omgchrome.com/duckduckgo-chrome-chrome-os/)?

Comment: @harrymc yes, I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you haven't got the `%s` in the query URL. Essentially, this indicates where Chrome should insert your query in the URL, which it then follows, hopefully leading you to the desired search results page.

So, try replacing the query URL, `http://duckduckgo.com`, with `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s`.